# Hibernate. Criteria Query for selecting by object from another class?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

This is a schema of my tables that I'm using for this:
[image]

I have a house, which can have several flats, each of those can have one water entry per month. `Water` object holds inside reference for `Flat`. `Flat` object holds reference for `House`. I want to select from database all entries based on current month and house. I tried doing this:

```
public static List<Water> getAll(Date date, House house){
    List<Water> waterList = null;
    Calendar myCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    myCalendar.setTime(date);
    myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
    Date monthStart = new java.sql.Date(myCalendar.getTimeInMillis());
    myCalendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,
                (myCalendar.getMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) - myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)));
    Date monthEnd = new java.sql.Date(myCalendar.getTimeInMillis());

    Session sess = mainApp.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction tx = null;
    try {
        tx = sess.beginTransaction();

        // create criteria builder
        CriteriaBuilder builder = sess.getCriteriaBuilder();
        // create criteria
        CriteriaQuery<Water> query = builder.createQuery(Water.class);
        // specify criteria root
        Root<Water> root = query.from(Water.class);

        query.select(root)
                .where(builder.and(builder.equal(root.get("house"), house),
                        builder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(root.get("date"), monthStart),
                        builder.lessThanOrEqualTo(root.get("date"), monthEnd)));
        waterList = sess.createQuery(query).getResultList();

        tx.commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        if (tx != null)
            tx.rollback();
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        sess.close();
    }

    return waterList;
}
```

But I got an error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to locate Attribute  with the the given name [house] on this ManagedType [home.accounting.model.Water]
```

As I understand this is because `Water` object doesn't have direct reference for house.

How should I modify my `Criteria Query`, so that I would be able to select all record in `Water` table based on house and date?

Comment: Did you try using root.get("flat").get("house")

Comment: it works! can you post it as an answer, so that I can accept it?

Comment: Added. Upvote it too. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you mentioned in the schema, Water has reference to flat and flat has reference to house, you can get house by first getting flat from root and then house from flat.

```
query.select(root)
                .where(builder.and(builder.equal(root.get("flat").get("house"), house),
                        builder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(root.get("date"), monthStart),
                        builder.lessThanOrEqualTo(root.get("date"), monthEnd)));
```